# Sinatra and Foursquare - undefined method `web_server'

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra, oauth-2.0, foursquare

I'm trying to run a simple Foursquare auth in Ruby with Sinatra. I am using the example [here](https://github.com/matthunter/foursquare-ruby-example).

When I try to run this code on my local server, I get this error

```
 NoMethodError at /
undefined method `web_server' for #<OAuth2::Client:0x16168bc>
```

I can't figure out how to fix this... Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `web_server` method was removed in v0.5.0 of the OAuth2 ruby gem.

install a prior version of the gem to make use of the missing method:

`gem install oauth2 -v 0.4.1`

and modify your script by adding the following line before the `require 'oauth2'` so it will only accept that particular version of the gem:

`gem 'oauth2', '=0.4.1'`

edit: looks like the example hasn't been updated for a while -- I [forked](https://github.com/wehal3001/foursquare-ruby-example) it and included the above suggested workaround (which has since been merged into the original repository).